How can I access the image Url from my API request in React?
I need to access the image URL for my products, when I retrieve the products it comes with all the payload yet when I insert it in a image tag it does not show up.
<td className="py-2 px-4 border-b">
    {product.imageURL && (
        <img
            src={`https://localhost:7214${product.imageURL}`} 
            className="h-16 w-16 rounded"
            alt={product.name}
        />
    )}
</td>

And yes I used the StaticFiles Middleware to give me the wwwroot and save the images there on creation. Yet when I used inspect element to check it showed as ==$0.
